# Which header file to #include for linking mincore.lib

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I want to write a C++ code for windows store. This application will be a EXE (and not any application container) so I'll use TSHELL to use this EXE on target phone.

I know that I can only use the APIs supported by "mincore.lib". This is teh MS link which gives list of APIs.

[MS APIs for
 mincore.lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn505783(v=vs.85).aspx)

But if I want to use individual APIs then do I need to explicitly includes the header files supported for each API like for example do I need to include "objbase.h" if I want to use the API "CLSIDFromProgID()".

Or **is there any single header file that I can include for using all the APIs of mincore.lib ?**

Answer (score 0):

Mincore is just a more efficient way of organizing linking. For the most part it won't change how you write apps. You'll still use the same headers you normally would. Generally speaking:

```
#include "Windows.h"
```

Unless you're an OEM you cannot write and deploy an unpackaged exe to a Windows Phone. It needs to be a packaged Windows Runtime or Silverlight app. If you are an OEM then check your OEM docs and OEM specific support offerings.